# Lync Contacts Not Syncing from Outlook Contacts

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, lync-2013

I have a user that has external contacts that she has added to Outlook and communicates with through Lync. All of these contacts have numbers and email addresses.

The user recently changed a number for one contact that she interacts with frequently. This is how the problem was found.

We discovered the contacts in Lync do not match the contacts in Outlook. Outlook is always up to date but Lync is falling out of sync. This means that the contact does not have a number on Lync and therefore cannot be contacted, even though the number is present in Outlook.

We have run a sync operation through a batch file but this only works for the length of the current log on session on the company network. When she turns off her machine on a night and returns to work the same fault happens.

How can I make sure the user's Lync contacts are synced? We cannot edit the logon script as this is a company wide logon script for a multinational company and this fault only affects this single user.

[Update]

As per the comments/answers I forgot to mention that the common fault with the Update for Communicator has been fixed company wide. and Lynch and Outlook have also been reinstalled in an attempt to fix this, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed that this was not an issue with the machine at all. the user was adding contacts to the wrong "Contacts" folder in outlook... this meant that they were not in the "Lync Contacts" folder hence they were not updating in Lync. I was told that the contacts were being added correctly so this completely slipped under my troubleshooting process... Anyway it is resolved thanks for all of your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem with Lync where the entire address book from the Outlook would not sync. I had tried may ways to Sync the contacts but could not succeed.

My suggestions:
1. Check if Lync communicator has any important update pending. If so apply the updates.
2. Remove the contact which is causing the issue and re-feed it to the outlook.

What I did was simply signout from Lync. Later exit from it. Wait for some 20-30 minutes. Login again to Lync. May be sometimes it takes time to sync the contact.

Comment: I have said I have forced the sync operation countless times and it worked till the user restarts the machine again and they disappear...

Comment: Please also do know that restarting the machine is not same as restarting the Lync. There is no much gain in restarting as it is not a system level operation. My answers are strictly relating to problems I faced and solution found. One may choose to apply it or discard.

Comment: The Lync Updates are all installed this has been dealt with before it is not a matter of just restarting lync. Outlook and Lync have been reinstalled in an attempt to fix this and still the same. The problems you had may have been different to this. I have tried everything you have stated in the answer (and stated this in my question)...